# Two simple loops are not vectorized by intel compiler

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, vector, icc

I have written a really simple code which dose vector addition. The source code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  long int n=10000;
  vector<double> a(n,0.0),b(n,0.0),c(n,0.0);

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    a[i]=i;
    b[i]=2*i;
  }

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

There are two loops in this code. The first loop (line 21-24) assigns value to vector `a` and `b`. The second loop (line 26-28) does the vector addition. In both loops, the iterations are independent of each other. According to my understanding, these two loops should be easily auto vectorized by the compiler.
However, I compiled the code with the intel compiler with flag `-opt-report`

```
icpc -opt-report main.cpp
```

I got a optimization report `main.optrpt`. In this report, however, it's shown that both loops are not vectorized. The details in the report are

```
LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(21,3)
   remark #15344: loop was not vectorized: vector dependence prevents vectorization. First dependence is shown below. Use level 5 report for details
   remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed ANTI dependence between  line  22 and  line 23
   remark #25438: unrolled without remainder by 2  
LOOP END

LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(26,3)
   remark #15344: loop was not vectorized: vector dependence prevents vectorization. First dependence is shown below. Use level 5 report for details
   remark #15346: vector dependence: assumed FLOW dependence between  line 27 and  line 27
   remark #25438: unrolled without remainder by 2  
LOOP END
```

Does anyone know why these two loops are not vectorized by the compiler?

Comment: As the message says, the compiler has trouble proving that the regions in a, b and c don't overlap. If they do overlap, the vectorization can change the result. To be safe , it doesn't vectorize. Some compilers would produce both versions of the code (vectorized and scalar) with a runtime test to determine if there is overlap and decide which version to use.

Comment: What is unclear about my comment? Repeating your misconception doesn't help... The problem is not with the loops themselves, it is with the storage, and vector hides from the compiler that a[i+1] and b[i] cannot refer to the same memory location. Maybe try `double*a=malloc(80000);` (or even `double a[10000];`) instead, although it will probably completely remove the loops in that case.

Comment: even though if there is no dependecie, if the compiler assumes that there might be one, vectorization will not happen, also pointer aliasing also prevent vectorization and "fp:precise" Flag also prevent vectorization if summation is in question, but since you are using integers dont know if that could be the issue